# Remove password from mercurial_keyring (TortoiseHg on Windows)

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, mercurial-keyring

I am running TortoiseHg on Windows XP.  I have the mercurial_keyring extension enabled.

Once a password is stored via the mercurial_keyring extension, is there any way to remove it?

A typical use case for this would be:

User A has no push privileges on a remote repository.  User B, who is co-located, does have push privileges.  User B enters his username and password on User A's machine to allow the push to happen.

How would I remove User B's credentials from User A's machine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Win32 API calls to CredRead and CredWrite are used to save to the keyring. In other words, mercurial_keyring is saving credentials that you can manage with Windows [Credential Manager](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306541) (Win7), for [XP it will be](http://www.interworks.com/blogs/jvalente/2010/02/02/removing-saved-credentials-passwords-windows-xp-windows-vista-or-windows-7) Run-`rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr`

From [other side](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mercurial_keyring)

> Passwords are identified by the combination of username and remote address

thus, if hg-username of UserB isn't public, UserA will not get privileges escalation

Comment: I came here because i was not able to find my Credential Manager in the settings, the options described in the linked KB Article are for some reason not available on my machine, but it turns out that
running `rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr` also works on Win7.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 7, you can follow the instructions [here](http://www.ayulin.net/blog/2012/how-to-removereset-a-mercurial-keyring-saved-password-on-windows/) (Control Panel -> User Accounts and Family Safety -> Credential Manager, and remove everything that says "Mercurial").

Answer (score 2):

In such a case I would probably just disable extension before pushing, still of course it is easy to forget it.

Having some way to clear the password is reasonable expectation, I will think about adding sth. Issue to follow: https://bitbucket.org/Mekk/mercurial_keyring/issue/45/some-way-to-clear-password-and-maybe

**Update** This is implemented since mercurial keyring 1.1.0 (published Nov 2015), mercurial keyring now brings

```
hg keyring_clear «path»
```

command which clears the password. It is less cute than using GUI tools, but works for any password backend (and uses exactly the same API  which is used to save the password and the same logic to pick the proper backend).

Comment: This command will only remove the password for the active user for this path (if several passwords had been stored, the not active ones will remain)

Comment: On Windows, it will also not clear the entry in the windows credential manager, it will only somehow invalidate the password.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 8 and 10 it is:

> Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager > Windows Credentials.